# splitting String in Android

Tags: android, string, textview

I am splitting a string using the following code in my Android app. But it's getting crashed. It is saying like PatternSyntaxException.

```
 String quotes_string = "1.agshjdgasfghsfjhsdfhjsfhjgj.#**#2.dfjngdhfkgjkfglkhjkh.#**#3.fdghjkhdgkklf";
 String[] apps = QuotesActivity.quotes_string.split("#**#");
 String quote = apps[0];
 txt_quotes.setText(quote);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to escape the '*' character. Change the regex to "#\\*\\*#".

Answer (score 3):

you can try as using Pattern Split:

```
 String quotes_string = "1.agshjdgasfghsfjhsdfhjsfhjgj.#**#2.
                                dfjngdhfkgjkfglkhjkh.#**#3.fdghjkhdgkklf";

 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#\\*\\*#");

 String[] apps =p.split(quotes_string);

 String quote = apps[0];
 txt_quotes.setText(quote);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
String quotes_string = "1.agshjdgasfghsfjhsdfhjsfhjgj.#**#2.dfjngdhfkgjkfglkhjkh.#**#3.fdghjkhdgkklf";

String[] apps = quotes_string.split("#\\*\\*#");
String quote = apps[0];
txt_quotes.setText(quote);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Java docs saying about PatternSyntaxException [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/PatternSyntaxException.html) as

> Unchecked exception thrown to indicate a syntax error in a
>   regular-expression pattern.

You can use PatternSplit suggested as above